# Workflow to delete record

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I want to write the workflow to prevent the delete of one particular record. Is this possible?
for example:
if Account Name is "ABC" then any user should not able to delete this particular record.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "Stop Workflow" specifying "Canceled" status in a Real-Time Workflow to be executed when record is deleted. The message you can specify in the properties of the "Stop Workflow" step will popup as error.